# Why mat-icon doesn't work in certain files?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I want to use mat-icons in my Angular project.

In src/app/files/files.html, I can use mat-icons, however, in src/app/files/public-file/public-file.html, mat-icon doesn't display.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Please add some details about the angular components. Are files and public-file components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forgot to import the class in app.module